# Swift 4 – Custom Alerts with protocols

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, alert

I'm having issues with Custom alerts and sending actions back to VC from which alert was called.

I have two classes:

- **Factory**
- **ConfirmationAllert**

User journey I'm trying to achieve:

The user performs actions in the `Factory` class after he finishes I call `ConfirmationAllert` using such code:

```
func showAlert() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConfirmationAllert")
    myAlert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
    myAlert.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
    (view as? UIViewController)?.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In `ConfirmationAllert` class I have button, which:

- dismisses alert
- sends action to **Factory** - this action is to dismiss **Factory** VC and go back to previous VC.

First action completes successfully, the second action not working. I'm using protocols to send the second action to `Factory` VC, but something is not working, and I don't know what.

Here is my code:

**Factory**

```
final class FactoryViewController: UIViewController {
    let alert = ConfirmationAllert()

    @IBAction func didPressSave(_ sender: UIButton) {
        showAlert() 
    }

    func goToPreviousVc() {
        alert.delegate = self
        print("Inside factory") -> print don't get called
        // navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) -> none of this works
        // dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) -> none of this works
    }
}

extension FactoryViewController: ConfirmationAllertDelegate {
    func dismissVC() {
        goToPreviousVc()
        print("Go to previous")
    }
}
```

**ConfirmationAllert**

```
protocol ConfirmationAllertDelegate {
    func dismissVC()
}

class ConfirmationAllert: UIViewController {
    var delegate: ConfirmationAllertDelegate?

    @IBAction func didPressOk(_ sender: UIButton) { 
        self.delegate?.dismissVC() 
    }
}
```

I didn't include `viewDidLoad` methods as I'm not calling anything there.

My issue is that method `goToPreviousVc()` doesn't perform any actions.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: So what the issue do you have?

Comment: @YuryImashev sorry, updated my question. Method `goToPreviousVc()` is not working. Nothing inside it get's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is that you setup your `ConfirmationAllertDelegate` at `goToPreviousVc` that supposed to be called using that delegate.

Instead, try to set up you delegate when you creating `myAlert` object

```
let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConfirmationAllert")
(myAlert as? ConfirmationAllert).delegate = self
// the rest of your code
```

After that, your alert will have a delegate since it was created and when you press the button, it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code

```
func showAlert() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConfirmationAllert") as! ConfirmationAllert
    myAlert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
    myAlert.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
    myAlert.delegate = self
    present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```